Программа не реагирует на изменение входных данных
Для чтения данных из файла применяю процедуру
matrix = [list(map(int, line.split())) for line in file]

Все работает. Но вот я вношу изменения в файл для чтения, а программа упорно их не замечает и выдает старые данные.
Перепробовал: пересохранение программы и файла, перезагрузку VS code и ПК - ничего не помогает. 
Как исправить?

Подозреваю, что ваша программа смотрит на один файл, а вы меняете другой. Другого объяснения, я не вижу

Этот файл один, путь к нему прописан, а куда смотрит программа, я ума не приложу.

Нашелся еще один такой же файл не затрагиваемый изменениями. Ваш ответ оказался верным, благодарю! Не вижу, как это отметить?

Никак. Ваш вопрос закроют как "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям." Да и я сделал лишь верное предположение, ибо другого не дано(еще оставался вариант, что в коде есть подмена файла или значений)
